# what is meaning of '_emit 0Fh, _emit 31h' in x86 assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

I want to check CPU cycle for my code.

and I want to use 'tsc'.

In this case, many codes of tsc contain '_emit 0Fh, _emit 31h'.

What is exact meaning of these??

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <windows.h>  

union int32to64
{

    __int64 i64;

    int i32[2];
};

void read_tsc(int *cl_Low, int *cl_High)
{

    __asm {
        _emit 0Fh
        _emit 31h
        mov ecx, dword ptr cl_Low // cl_Low -> ecx into 32bit
        mov[ecx], eax
        mov ecx, dword ptr cl_High
        mov[ecx], edx
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    union int32to64 a, b;
    __int64 mhz = 0;

    read_tsc(&a.i32[0], &a.i32[1]);
    Sleep(1000);
    read_tsc(&b.i32[0], &b.i32[1]);

    mhz = b.i64 - a.i64;

    printf("clock : %I64dMHz", mhz / 1000000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As inline assembly is not part of the C standard, it's an extension of the compiler. And as we don't know what compiler you're using we can't reliable tell you anything. We can *guess* and *infer* but we can't give a definitive answer without all details.

Comment: You can and should use an intrinsic for `rdtsc` that doesn't store the result to memory, forcing the compiler to reload it after the `asm` block.  (IDK if you can do this with MSVC inline-asm, but that's why you should use an intrinsic the compiler understands *instead* of inline-asm).  i.e. [`__int64 _rdtsc (void)` from `immintrin.h`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=1825,5214,433,720,4251&text=rdtsc) should be portable to all compilers that support Intel intrinsics.  This code you found is probably ancient, predating support for the intrinsic.

Comment: With MSVC you might have to use a double underscore version [__rdtsc()](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/cpp/intrinsics/rdtsc), but otherwise like Peter Cordes says.

Answer (score 8):

`0f 31` is the opcode for the rdtsc instruction.  The two `_emit` pseudo-instructions emit these two bytes, effectively forming an rdtsc instruction.  It is possible that this code was written for a compiler that doesn't support the rdtsc mnemonic.  Manually emitting the bytes that make up the instruction is one possible workaround for such cases.